# google spreadsheet custom script permission to get a range from another document to a custom sript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I created a custom function in script editor

```
function contributionOfEmployee(name) {
    var participants = SpreadsheetApp.openById(name).getSheetByName("Oct").getRange("A3:B10").getValues();
    Logger.log(participants);
}
```

With this above function I get the error in the sheet I am invoking the above function from.

> "You do not have permission to perform that action. (line 2)."

However when I run the function from the script editor itself, then it works fine without any problem, however when invoked from a spreadsheet, it gives permission problem.

How do I ensure the above function has permissions to lookup specified range from another document?

Comment: How are you passing the Spreadsheet ID? Are you running the command or someone else?

Comment: The spreadsheet id is passed as argument to this function. The function is invoked from a spreadsheet that I own.

Answer (score 1):

If your custom function throws the error message "You do not have permission to call X service.", the service requires user authorization and thus cannot be used in a custom function. Essentially custom functions are only allowed to read data from the current spreadsheet.This is due to a change in GAS introduced somewhere in June 2015.

Also if you want to invoke the function from the spreadsheet it should have a **return** value to display in the cell the function was called from.

See also [here.](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5174)